# How to check permissions in a zip on RHEL?

Tags: zip, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have very little exposure to RHEL, and was quite surprised to find that `unzip -l` and `unzip -lv` do not include file permissions. I see that extracting files eventually restores the permissions, but I am wondering if there is a way to check the permissions without unzipping.

As you can see in the command line interaction below, `ex` is executable and `nonex` is not and which `unzip` restores the permissions for both, but I want to see the permissions without unzipping

```
/tmp> ls -lgG *ex
-rwxrwxr-x 1 0 Feb 17 04:26 ex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Feb 17 04:26 nonex
/tmp> zip -qq  perms *ex
/tmp> unzip -l perms.zip
Archive:  perms.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  02-17-2015 04:26   ex
        0  02-17-2015 04:26   nonex
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
/tmp> unzip -lv perms.zip
Archive:  perms.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 02-17-2015 04:26 00000000  ex
       0  Stored        0   0% 02-17-2015 04:26 00000000  nonex
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       0                0   0%                            2 files
/tmp> unzip -qq -d perms perms.zip
/tmp> ls -lgG perms
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 0 Feb 17 04:26 ex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Feb 17 04:26 nonex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zipinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zipinfo) to display permissions. Keep in mind depending on where the archive is generated, permissions may not reflect actual source system permissions (this is especially true if you are extracting an archive generated in Windows).

Here is a snippet from the documentation of `zipinfo` that details the output format, which is based on the familiar `ls -l` (long) listing format. The first field details the permissions.

> `-rw-rws---  1.9 unx    2802 t- defX 11-Aug-91 13:48 perms.2660`
>
> The last three fields are the modification date and time of the file,
>   and its name. The case of the filename is respected; thus files that
>   come from MS-DOS PKZIP are always capitalized. If the file was zipped
>   with a stored directory name, that is also displayed as part of the
>   filename.
>
> The second and third fields indicate that the file was zipped under
>   Unix with version 1.9 of zip. Since it comes from Unix, the file
>   permissions at the beginning of the line are printed in Unix format.
>   The uncompressed file-size (2802 in this example) is the fourth field.
>
> The fifth field consists of two characters, either of which may take
>   on several values. The first character may be either 't' or 'b',
>   indicating that zip believes the file to be text or binary,
>   respectively; but if the file is encrypted, zipinfo notes this fact by
>   capitalizing the character ('T' or 'B'). The second character may also
>   take on four values, depending on whether there is an extended local
>   header and/or an ''extra field'' associated with the file (fully
>   explained in PKWare's APPNOTE.TXT, but basically analogous to pragmas
>   in ANSI C--i.e., they provide a standard way to include non-standard
>   information in the archive). If neither exists, the character will be
>   a hyphen ('-'); if there is an extended local header but no extra
>   field, 'l'; if the reverse, 'x'; and if both exist, 'X'. Thus the file
>   in this example is (probably) a text file, is not encrypted, and has
>   neither an extra field nor an extended local header associated with
>   it.